# Use of IN, EXISTS and ANY/SOME

Tags: sql, t-sql, exists, any

I am trying to optimize some stored procedures and they are very frequently using EXISTS, ANY or IN and I want to know the difference in what specific scenario which is best either IN, Exists or ANY.

I created three queries using IN, EXISTS and ANY and checked the execution cycle of them but the execution cycle of all three queries are same. I am confused why it is coming same, how can the execution cycle be different or what are the scenarios where it can be different. Below are the three queries and execution cycle of them that I tried. Can anyone give me an example how the execution cycle can be changed, please share any scenario or query.

### Query using EXISTS

One more question here in the subquery, what is the need of * or columns specified?

```
SELECT * FROM RecastEvents AS re
    WHERE EXISTS (Select * FROM Metadata 
                      WHERE EventId = 2145984 AND EventId = re.CCId)
```

[image: Execution Cycle of Exists]

### Query using IN

```
SELECT * FROM RecastEvents as re
    WHERE re.CCID IN (SELECT EventId FROM Metadata
                          WHERE EventId = 2145984)
```

[image: Execution Cycle of IN]

### Query using ANY

```
SELECT * FROM RecastEvents AS re
    WHERE re.CCID = ANY (SELECT EventId FROM Metadata 
                             WHERE EventId = 2145984)
```

[image]

Comment: For `where exists (select *`, SQL knows it doesn't need to retrieve `*`, that's not an issue.

Comment: Try these queries without a hard coded EventId and instead select all Recast Events with a matching metadata entry. The plans may be more informative.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Yes i removed condition in all three queries but only for the EXISTS, it changed the cost but not the execution plan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is coming out the same because the query optimizer is doing its job.

One of the purposes of SQL (and similar languages) is that you write a query specifying *what* you want, and not *how* you want it, and let the query system deal with the how.

In this case the query optimizer rules end up with the same actual query execution plan. This may or may not change depending on the volume of data later on. My guess is it won't.

As for the `*` in the first, you can try with `1` instead and it'll work out fine, it is used as a placeholder for "data" in this case.

Comment: You can even put `1/0` in place of the `*` to prove to yourself that it is not even evaluated.

Comment: Thanks Lasse. Got it, but can you share any of the query that can distinguish execution plan among them.

Answer (score 2):

In sql server 2005 and older versions, EXISTS would be faster coz once its found its record, it will come out of process. Whereas IN will collect all the data from sub query for processing.

But in latest versions of sql server query optimizer is smart enough to generate typically better plan